# Uri to Bitmap Then Transfer Another Activity

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to provide bitmap through uri after that provided bitmap transfer another activity how can I do it??

I find a few ways to convert uri I was unsuccessful

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
    picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I try to implement that codes I was in failure

```
Uri IMAGE_URI = imageReturned
                InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(IMAGE_URI);
                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream );
                picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

That is another way which my tried code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            picture.setImageURI(resultUri);
        } 
        else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Merroor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can I provide bitmap from uri for implementation to my codes?

Comment: Using `Glide` library to load from `Uri` then display on your view.